# How to retrieve text from a webpage in Java?

Tags: java, text, web, artificial-intelligence

I'm a complete noob to the Java programming language.
I have some (Emphasis on 'some') experience in Python, BASIC, and programming in general. I've made a few programs, nothing of note.

I have decided to begin one a fairly daunting project in order to:
A) Develop a profound understanding of Java
B) Create an extremely useful tool lucrative to my everyday life
C) Gain some experience in programming

I have decided to create an AI which I have named 'S.E.R.V.A.N.T.'. Currently he is nothing more than an idea, but that is why I am here.

**MY PROBLEM:**
I want to make Servant retrieve text from the web, News, Weather, Movie Listings etc.

I have searched high and low and have been unable to find an adequate solution to my issue, could anyone help?

I have 0 experience with Java applets, though I have a fundamental understanding of the language itself. If you could explain your response, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: if there is a common, specific formats then a simple file i/o for each line and process it (some preprocessing)

Comment: i would.not advice a beginer to start TEXT MINING as a 1st java project . **if its your project then, make a project to get used to file i/o (make a swing form,accept username and email ,store to file : list all button to give a complete list)

Comment: I'd start choosing those text sources that have RSS, so you could use easily extract well-formed text, instead of wasting time with mundane tasks such as parsing html or extracting text using XPATH or whatever.

Comment: Another thing that I'd strongly recommend to you is to narrow your scope first. Try to identify a very specific problem that you want to solve so you can keep focus. Data Mining (or text mining) is just a tool to solve a real-world problem. Don't go the other way, just trying to find solutions first for artificial problems. Many times, data mining's value is to just understand the problem better before actually attacking it, IMO.

Comment: @Leo: I appreciate the speedy reply! And I completely understand, I've tackled many projects and failed because my focus was broad and shallow as opposed to eliminating one issue at a time. My goal is to have my program tell me the news(Which I will be targeting first), weather, movie times etc.(Which will come directly after). Is there another way to retrieve this information other than parsing or extracting? I'm unfamiliar with the term RSS

Comment: @SrinathGanesh: This is my first major java project, I've done multiple small projects involving I/O, like a simplistic text-based strategy game I recently finished. I wish to tackle this project and believe with the help of others I could complete this. I appreciate the advice though.

Comment: @Servant well, getting familiar to the term RSS is a nice starting point then :-)

Comment: @Leo Thank you very much for merely mentioning this, apparently Yahoo has RSS for everything I need! Now I just need to figure out how to use it and I should be fine! :D

Answer (score 2):

Javascript would probably be better for something of this nature. It has much more intuitive parsing methods.

If you insist on using java, you can read in the HTML code as a string with the below code:

```
package test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class ConvertUrlToString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            String webPage = "http://www.google.com";
            URL url = new URL(webPage);
            URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
            InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);

            int numCharsRead;
            char[] charArray = new char[1024];
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            while ((numCharsRead = isr.read(charArray)) > 0) {
                sb.append(charArray, 0, numCharsRead);
            }
            String result = sb.toString();

            System.out.println("*** BEGIN ***");
            System.out.println(result);
            System.out.println("*** END ***");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the speedy reply as well! I appreciate the code, but I'm afraid I don't understand it in the slightest (._.') A few questions, 
1) Why have it in a 'try' loop? 
2) What is going on with the 'URL url = new URL(webPage);'? 
3) And how might I put this in an applet?

I apologize for my ignorance, I'm merely trying to understand, and thanks again

Comment: @Servant 1) try **block** not loop (exception handling)   2) Create URL object with web address  3) (I am a student myself) i feel applet is NOT for processing part , just client side display part & its a lot old (**try javaFX but its not easy !**) , and applet some packages like database restricted for security reasons